# How can I get upload success status with Amazon Web Services?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am working on an Android projet in which I use Amazon Web Services (AWS) to store files. I have this:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client( new BasicAWSCredentials(myId, myKey) );
s3Client.putObject( new PutObjectRequest(myBucketName, myObjectKey, myFile) );
```

It has been proven successful as I can see the files in Amazon's database. What I want to know is if I can get a success status. I want to be able to execute code if the upload was successful, and other code otherwise. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922724/amazons3-how-to-check-if-the-upload-succeeded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the AWS S3 JavaDoc:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest%29

> Amazon S3 never stores partial objects; if during this call an exception wasn't thrown, the entire object was stored.

Therefore, the PutObjectResult object being returned successfully is indicative of a successful call (i.e. the object was uploaded).  If there are permission errors, an AmazonServiceException will be thrown:

> AmazonServiceException - If any errors occurred in Amazon S3 while processing the request.

**EDIT 1** In the answer referenced in an above comment (suggesting the OP download the file that was just uploaded and compare the downloaded copy against the original), you're essentially paying for an upload and a download, which I would think is overkill for most use cases.  Instead, use the information provided in the PutObjectResult class and just verify use the existence of that information as evidence of a successful upload.  It's not precise confirmation, but you're likely fine relying on the S3 guarantee of success if no exception was thrown.

Keep in mind the below constraints of uploading a file vs. a stream.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest%29

> When uploading a file:
>
> - The client automatically computes a checksum of the file. Amazon S3
>     uses checksums to validate the data in each file.
> - Using the file extension, Amazon S3 attempts to determine the correct
>     content type and content disposition to use for the object.
>
> When uploading directly from an input stream:
>
> - Be careful to set the correct content type in the metadata object
>     before directly sending a stream. Unlike file uploads, content types
>     from input streams cannot be automatically determined. If the caller
>     doesn't explicitly set the content type, it will not be set in Amazon
>     S3.
> - Content length must be specified before data can be uploaded to Amazon
>     S3. Amazon S3 explicitly requires that the content length be sent in
>     the request headers before it will accept any of the data. If the
>     caller doesn't provide the length, the library must buffer the
>     contents of the input stream in order to calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

If there was an error during upload, you will get an exception. the putObject method returns a PutObjectResult object with the newly uploaded file properties.

SDK: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.File)